# Why is .properties file read differently by DispatcherPortlet and MVCPortlet?

Tags: encoding, liferay, portlet

I am developing a Liferay Portal, where I have 2 different types of portlets:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    <resource-bundle>path.to.Resource</resource-bundle>
    ...
</portlet>
```

and

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>HELP</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    <resource-bundle>path.to.Resource</resource-bundle>
    ...
</portlet>
```

The problem is that the first portlet reads the resource bundle in ISO-8859-1 encoding, while the second one in UTF-8. This results to displaying special characters like äöüß in a weird way in one of the portlets. If the resource bundle (.properties file) contains ä then it is being displayed weirdly in the first portlet. If the resource bundle contains an UTF-8 encoded \u00E4 then is being displayed wrongly in the second portlet. What could be the reason and how could it be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Liferay assumes resources to be UTF-8, the only way to work around this is to have two different resource files for both portlets. This is unfortunate, but the only solution I can think of.